# How do_async_page_fault is called?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, interrupt, interrupt-handling, page-fault

I was looking into linux internals of how interrupts are handled by kernel. I couldn't find the way **do_async_page_fault** api is called. As far as my understanding goes, this is stored as function pointer and called when interrupt occurs. can you explain exactly how?